# Retrieving multiple images (by using loops if possible) if we only know the url and have no information about the web service in android

Tags: android, uiimageview, url-routing

I have a URL and there are a lot of images (At least 3000 or more) placed on it. All the images are like href. If I click on title of an image, it opens up. What i want is to use these images in my project. I can do it easily by using Picasso RecyclerView and Async class provided I have a web service for this thing.

Right now, with only the URL I have, I have no idea of how to get images and make a loop or something else to gather the next image. I can copy paste all the URL's in an array by clicking on the href and copying in string.xml or in some array but i don't want to because there are 100's of images and it doesn't worth to do it this way.

Can some body give me a start of how we can get images from URL if we dont have the JSON or xml.

**EDITED**

This is my Async class

```
Context context;
private IAsyncTaskListener listener;
ProgressBar progressBar;

public ArrayList<String> linkArray = new ArrayList<>();
public HTMLAsync(Context context, IAsyncTaskListener listener, ProgressBar progressBar) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
   // dataArray.clear();
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

    File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://mobileswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/");

    Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
    Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
    for (Element link : links) {
        String linkHref = link.attr("href");
        linkArray.add(linkHref);
        String linkText = link.text();
    }} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;

    }
    return true;
}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if (result==true) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.listener.onCompleted(linkArray);
    } else
        Toast.makeText(context,"Check your Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
public interface IAsyncTaskListener {
    void onCompleted(List<String> linkArray);
}
}
```

And this is my Adapter class I am using

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
List<String> linkArray;
private int lastPosition = -1;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
    //this.dataArray = dataArray;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void setDataArray(List<String> linkArray) {
    this.linkArray = linkArray;

}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
    CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(linkArray.get(position)).into(holder.image);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return linkArray.size();
}


public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView image;

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}


}
```

Main Activity class is:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
ProgressBar progressBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new HTMLAsync(getApplicationContext(), this, progressBar).execute();

}

@Override
public void onCompleted(List<String> linkArray) {
    // Initializing the Recycler View and its layout
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerViewAdapter.setDataArray(linkArray);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

I have included the Picasoo and JSoup library and also the recyclerview and cardview support library in gradle file as well.

This is the LOGCAT generated when i try to execute this and I do not know what really is the cause.

```
 E/lowmemorykiller: Kernel does not support memory pressure events or in-    kernel low memory killer
 04-02 02:05:46.746 963-963/? E/CameraService: setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
 04-02 02:05:46.856 1019-1019/? E/perfprofd: unable to open configuration file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/perfprofd.conf
 04-02 02:05:46.995 952-952/? E/SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
 04-02 02:05:47.640 952-977/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
 04-02 02:05:51.636 966-966/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
 04-02 02:05:51.636 966-966/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
 04-02 02:05:51.820 963-963/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
 04-02 02:05:51.820 963-1284/? E/AudioFlinger: no wake lock to update!
 04-02 02:05:51.821 963-963/? E/AudioFlinger: int android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or directory)
 04-02 02:05:51.821 963-963/? E/SoundTriggerHwService: couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
 04-02 02:05:51.822 963-963/? E/RadioService: couldn't load radio module radio.primary (No such file or directory)
 04-02 02:05:51.858 959-959/? E/Netd: cannot find interface dummy0
 04-02 02:05:52.606 966-966/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NanumGothic.ttf
 04-02 02:05:52.606 966-966/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf
 04-02 02:05:52.606 966-966/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/MTLmr3m.ttf
 04-02 02:05:53.188 966-966/? E/EmojiFactory_jni: Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found
 04-02 02:05:54.443 966-966/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.pat.txt
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
 at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207) 
 at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114) 
 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96) 
 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
```

Comment: "I have a URL and there are alot of images (Atleast 3000 or more) placed on it" -- a URL itself does not have images. A Web page might have references to images, and a URL might point to a Web page. "All the images are like href" -- do you mean that this URL, when requested by an HTTP client, returns an HTML page with some sort of references to the images?

Comment: Yes exactly this is the case !

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Choose [an HTML parsing library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/42).

Step #2: Add that library to your project.

Step #3: Follow the instructions in that library to parse the HTML associated with that URL and extract the URLs for your images.

Make sure to do this work in a background thread. Once you have your list of URLs, you can populate your `RecyclerView`, using Picasso to retrieve the images as needed.

Comment: Alright, i ll give it a try and ll let u know with results afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {
String linkHref = link.attr("href");
String linkText = link.text();
}
```